# MFC: how to access scroll bar when CScrollView is used?

Tags: mfc

I create a project with the following settings.

```
  + Application type: Single document
  + Use Unicode libraries: NO
  + Project style: MFC standard
  + Use of MFC: Use MFC in a shared DLL
  + Base class: CScrollView
```

I only modify OnDraw to output lots of lines.

```
void CMRCView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    CMRCDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    // TODO: add draw code for native data here

    CFont font;
    int font_pixels_height;

    /* set up font and figure out its height, omit here ... */

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    rect.bottom = font_pixels_height;

    CFont *old_font = pDC->SelectObject(&font);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        pDC->DrawText("hello world 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789",
                      -1, &rect, DT_LEFT);
        rect.top += font_pixels_height;
        rect.bottom += font_pixels_height;
    }

    pDC->SelectObject(old_font);
}
```

The output is OK. When I expand the window I can see more lines, but there is no scroll bar either vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read more carefully the documentation. The `CScrollView` class defines relatively few additional (to its base class `CView`) methods. It will automatically display scroll-bars if the scrollable area is bigger than the visible client area. Some key methods are `SetScrollSizes()`, `GetScrollPosition()` and `GetClientRect()` (inherited from `CWnd`).

Recalculate the scrollable area's size (and call `SetScrollSizes()`) in any case this may be needed - for example a change in the data in your `CDocument`, or when the user changes some "View Options".

Then there are two ways to paint (`OnDraw()`) your document:

- Paint the whole scrollable area. This is very simple to implement, but somehow "wasteful", as it may paint an area that is not visible.
- Paint only the visible part of the scrollable area. Call `GetTotalSize()` (or just check the values you previously passed to `SetScrollSizes()` - you will have to store them), `GetClientRect()` and `GetScrollPosition()` to determine what you need to paint. You should only paint the rectangle returned by `GetClientRect()` (you need to offset it by the scroll position, returned by `GetScrollPosition()`).

In either case you must also check if the scrollable size is rather smaller than the visible client rectangle), and in both the horizontal and vertical directions. If so, fill the rest with some neutral color, indicating a "no-data" or "empty" area. Better use a standard system color, returned by `GetSysColor()` (eg `COLOR_3DFACE` or `COLOR_BTNFACE`), or some custom darker brush.

Comment: Thank you. So literally I need to figure out the total displaying area even before any display happens. For a simple spreadsheet it might be easy. But in my case, I think I may need to go through every record due to caveats like different fonts and text wrapping. Is there any easier way to calculate?

Comment: Can't answer this because I don't know what your data are. It may be easier if your document consists of fixed-length pages, but a lot harder if their length is variable. The `CScrollView` implementation requires that the size of the document be known in advance (but it can still be changed). I have used it only in imaging applications, and there of course the size of an image was known as soon as it was opened.