# MFC - A new string is not drawn after ScrollWindow. What could be the cause?

Tags: mfc

There is a issue with `ScrollWindow()`. In `OnPaint()`, there is `TextOut(0, 100, L"XXX")`, which means the string `XXX` should be always at coord `(0, 100)`. When I scroll the CChildView with `ScrollWindow()`, the drawn string moves -- this is expected. But a new string `XXX` is not drawn at coord `(0, 100)`.

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    dc.TextOut(0, 100, L"XXX"); // XXX should always locate at (0, 100)
}
```

`ScrollWindow(0, -10)` scrolls the contents of CChildView down by 10px, and calls `OnPaint()` indirectly. In this case, the string `XXX` should move up by 10px, locating at (0, 90), and a new string `XXX` should be drawn at `(0, 100)`.

But now the problem is, the new string is not drawn at all. What could be the cause?

Comment: `ScrollWindow()` does not invalidate the entire window, but only the part that is "uncovered". If the string does not overlap the uncovered part, it won't be painted. Try with a position that is at the uncovered region near the bottom of the window.

Comment: For a view you should better use `OnDraw()` rather than `OnPaint()` - the default implementation of `OnPaint()` calls `OnDraw()` with a paint DC, after having called `OnPrepareDC()`. The dc's coordinates are relative to the scroll-area (set by a previous call to `SetScrollSizes()`). You can call `GetScrollPosition()` to determine the area that need to be drawn. Take a look at my replies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60555216/mfc-how-to-access-scroll-bar-when-cscrollview-is-used/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66858300/mfc-cscrollview-does-not-clear-background).

Comment: I tested it. You're right. Thank you. @j6t